# Log4net to write multiple files in each and every process when we trigger the events

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

We have added log4net.config file in our project;

```
<log4net>
<appender name="ErrorLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMddHHmmssfff.'txt'" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d{DATE} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="ErrorLog">
  <maximumFileSize value="15MB" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorLog" />
</logger>
```

we need to log all the messages in every second when we trigger the events but problem is that a new log file created after each and every minute but instead that we need to generate new log file whenever we manually click on a particular button.  Any help would be appreciated.